# 'CI_Controller' not found in

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I got this controller Email_Controller.php, and whenever I try to call a function of it via JavaScript it just gives me this error: 
- `Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in C:\wamp64\www\Projeto\application\controllers\Email_Controller.php on line <i>2</i>`

My Controller looks like this:

```
<?php
     class Email_Controller extends CI_Controller {
         public function SendEmail(){
             //SomeCode
         }
     }
```

any idea on whats going on? My Main Controller is just working fine...

this is my JS

```
function teste() {
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'application/controllers/Main_Controller.php/SendEmail',
    data: {Post_email: email, Post_name: name},
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(response); 
    },
    error: function(response){
        console.log("error");
        console.log(response); 
    }
});
```

}

My routes.php 
`$route['default_controller'] = 'Main_Controller';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;`

Answer (score 1):

It can't be found because you link your url in ajax incorrectly.

use this: `url: "<?php echo base_url('Main_Controller/SendEmail') ?>",`

> FYI don't use the extension .php when you call the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change right Path. Remember First Set the config  base_url at application/ config/ config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://siteurl.com/';
```

Then Set the right path in JS URL.

```
url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Main_Controller.php/SendEmail',
```